# what is the right concept for declaring instance of getx in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am learning flutter and working all fine but i dont know why all user declare instance inside build method...does not it call each time of rebuild? is that ok?

So what is the difference between these two declaration

```
class PlaySongScreenHeader extends StatelessWidget {
  const PlaySongScreenHeader({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//declaring inside build method
    SongPlayerController songPlayerController=Get.put(SongPlayerController());
```

second way is

```
class PlaySongScreenHeader extends StatelessWidget {
  PlaySongScreenHeader({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
//declaring inside class
SongPlayerController songPlayerController=Get.put(SongPlayerController());
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference between declaring an instance of GetX inside the `build` method and outside the `build` method lies in the lifecycle and performance considerations.

When anything is initialized in the `build` method, and the widget is rebuilt, it will lead to unnecessary reinitializes. You can only declare when something needs context, like

```
Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
```

so, this is the best approach:

```
class PlaySongScreenHeader extends StatelessWidget {
  PlaySongScreenHeader({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
//declaring inside class
SongPlayerController songPlayerController=Get.put(SongPlayerController());
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```